# Assign different operators during python loop

Tags: python, operators

I would like to assign loop results to a contineous operator, for instance:

```
for x in xrange(1, 5):
    answer = 5 + x
```

How can I replace this with:

```
for x in xrange(1, 5):
    answerx = 5 + x
```

Meaning, assigning the answers to answer1, answer2, etc.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Why do you think you want to do that? In general, if you think want to dynamically name variables including numbers, you really wanted a list instead.

Comment: you could use the module with yield for a generator
`def answers(min=1,max=5):
    for x in xrange(min,max):
       yield 5+x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a list:

```
answers = []
for x in xrange(1, 5):
    answers.append(5 + x)
```

Then you can access the answers as `answers[0]` and so on.

...but a list comprehension is even nicer, as in Martijn Pieters' answer.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.  Will try the others as well, but is was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Append answers to a list, or better still, use a list comprehension:

```
answers = [5 + x for x in xrange(1, 5)]
```

Now you can address `answers[0]`, `answers[1]`, etc.

You can also make it a dictionary:

```
answers = {'answer{}'.format(x): 5 + x for x in xrange(1, 5)}
```

Whenever you feel the urge to generate variable names from data, you are *probably* looking to use a dictionary or list instead. [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: it would be more optimal to use lists for a generator "(5 + x for x in xrange(1,5))", but i say 1+ for list comprehension too! :D

Comment: @markcial: That depends on how the OP is planning to use the output.

Answer (score 2):

From first comments, giving complete example :

```
answer = []
for x in xrange(1,5) :
  answer.append(5 + x)
```

and as said list comprehension is more Python-way of doing this

> answer = [5+x for x in xrange(1,5)]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want to do that, but here's a solution (try this on ipython):

```
for x in xrange(1, 5):
    locals()["answer"+str(x)] = 5 + x
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution to your question is:

```
for x in xrange(1,5):
   exec("answer"+str(x)+"= 5 + x")
```

like this, you can use answer1, answer2... as individual variables. Some people might say that is is not a "good practise", but I use this statement from time to time an find it very useful for certain applications...

Comment: In addition to being awful style and completely unnecessary (even if creating variables dynamically was acceptable), it also doesn't work inside functions (in Python 3 at least).